# Regex to match a pattern with same number in R

Tags: regex, r

I have set of strings which looks like the below. Each string has 3 numbers separated with an underscore (_). Each number is a value between 1 - 100.

> ma_1_1_1
>
> ma_2_100_59
>
> ma_29_29_29
>
> ma_100_100_100
>
> ma_7_72_78
>
> ma_10_10_100
>
> ma_4_4_49

I want to write a regular expression where I can get the strings whose digits are all same. For example my output would be

> ma_1_1_1, ma_29_29_29 and ma_100_100_100

Comment: NB, the *digits* aren’t all the same; the *numbers* are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use back-references to make a regex match a previous group again:

```
ma_(100|[1-9][0-9]?)_\1_\1\b
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS5pT7/3)

This will also validate that the numbers are within range. If this validation is unnecessary, use `(\d+)` for the capture group.

Comment: I executed the regex as follows 
grep("ma_(100|[1-9][0-9]?)(_\\1)(_\\1), stringList, value = T). However it did select these values for the output as well ma_9_9_91, ma_6_6_66, ma_4_4_45,  ma_10_10_100 and ma_1_1_100. 
I modified the expression as grep("ma_(100|[1-9][0-9])(_\\1)(_\\1)", stringList, value = T). I got a partially correct solution (couldn't get the numbers below 10 and ma_10_10_100 is coming up in the output). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @SriniShine No, it makes sense that it would match that. Try adding `\b` to the end of the regex. (It's a word-boundary assertion)

Comment: I think this time it worked. However had to modify the expression a bit. ma_(100|[1-9][0-9] captured everything beginning with 10. Therefore I added another alternative clause.  
grep("ma_(100|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])(_\\1)(_\\1)\\b", stringList, value = T). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
^ma_(\d+)_\1_\1$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/bU1gT4/3).
This uses backreferences with the first captured group as well as anchors.

Comment: I didn't dvote but it could possibly be generalized for any length of repeating numbers, not just two, and written in R `grep("ma_(\\d+)(_\\1)+", x)`

Comment: Thank you @Jan for the answer

Comment: @Jan I executed the regex as follows 
grep("ma_(\\d+)(_\\1)(_\\1)", stringList, value = T). However it did select these values for the output as well ma_9_9_91, ma_6_6_66, ma_4_4_45,  ma_10_10_100 and ma_1_1_100. I got a partially correct solution with 4castle's method. However still working on it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @SriniShine: Updated the answer, use anchors additionally.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a modification to @4castle which will only extract the strings with similar numbers.

```
grep("ma_(100|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])(_\\1)(_\\1)\\b", stringList, value = T)
```